# How do I drop a table from SQLite3 in DJango?

Tags: database, django, sqlite

I made a model, and ran python manage.py syncdb. I think that created a table in the db. Then I realized that I had made a column incorrectly, so I changed it, and ran the same command, thinking that it would drop the old table, and add a new one.

Then I went to python manage.py shell, and tried to run .objects.all(), and it failed, saying that column  doesn't exist.

I want to clear out the old table, and then run syncdb again, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: This is by design.  Synchronizing alters and drops would open a giant can of worms.  George has the right answer for you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Another simple way to do this while using Django 1.4 or below, would be

```
python manage.py reset app_name
```

which drops and re-creates the tables used by the models of this app.

This was deprecated in Django 1.3 and is no longer available from Django 1.5

Comment: This was the solution I used. Worked perfectly.

Comment: the reset command has been deprecated in Django 1.3 and is no longer available from Django 1.5. Please check my answer.

Comment: Current version supports::  python manage.py reset_db

Answer (score 72):

to clear out an application is as simple as writing:

```
./manage.py sqlclear app_name | ./manage.py dbshell
```

then in order to rebuild your tables just type:

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: No longer works in Django 1.9+:
[Deprecations in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9)

Answer (score 47):

None of the answers shows how to delete just one table in an app. It's not too difficult. The [`dbshell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dbshell) command logs the user into the sqlite3 shell.

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

When you are in the shell, type the following command to see the structure of your database. This will show you all the table names in the database (and also the column names within tables).

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

In general, Django names tables according to the following convention: "appname_modelname". Therefore, SQL query that accomplishes your goal will look similar to the following:

```
DROP TABLE appname_modelname;
```

This should be sufficient, even if the table had relationships with other tables. Now you can log out of SQLITE shell by executing:

```
.exit
```

If you run syncdb again, Django will rebuild the table according to your model. This way, you can update your database tables without losing all of the app data. If you are running into this problem a lot, consider using South - a django app that will migrate your tables for you.

Comment: YOu have the more version-proof basic-principles answer here. I'll just add you need to have sqlite3 installed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the mention of `dbshell` -- I have used `shell` before, but after swapping out my DB for mysql, it doesn't seem to allow me to access my models anymore. The `dbshell` now plugs me right into my mysql shell -- very cool.

Comment: From Schdiewie Kay's answer:  after you follow all the above steps, run "manage.py migrate --run-syncdb" instead of "syncdb" for Django 1.9+

Answer (score 25):

get the DROP statements with

`python manage.py sqlclear app_name`

then try

`python manage.py dbshell`

and execute the DROP statement

check out http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

Comment: This is the answer I figured was out there. Thank you. It happens that the reset command worked nicely.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem.

For a quick resolve (if you don't care about losing your tables/data), correct your models.py file with the desired data types, delete the Migration folder and db.SQLite3 file,

then re-run the following commands:

1. python manage.py migrate
2. python manage.py makemigrations
3. python manage.py migrate
4. python manage.py createsuperuser (to create an admin user/pswd to manage admin page)
5. python manage.py runserver

Comment: This was the only solution I could get to work.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be the only working solution. Highly underrated answer.

Comment: Yep, that really helped, thanx. 
But when I deleted the migration folder, `makemigrations` command didn't recognized my models. So I had to recreate that folder and put `__init__.py` in it, then everything worked fine.

Comment: @kat Russo What if don't want to delete data ?

Comment: @NoMercy try 'python manage.py makemigrations appname' next time

Answer (score 5):

In Django 2.1.7, I've opened the `db.sqlite3` file in [SQLite browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) (there is also a Python package on [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/sqlite_bro/)) and deleted the table using command

```
DROP TABLE appname_tablename;
```

and then

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE App='appname';
```

Then run again

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate appname
```

Comment: Deleting the entire migrations folder made this work

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth expanding on a few answers here:

So, you can get access to the `dbshell` with the following command:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

It is then preferential to use the following:

```
DROP TABLE appname_tablename CASCADE;
```

To drop any related tables, effectively mirroring the "on_delete=CASCADE" direction on a field.

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.9 I had to do Kat Russo's steps, but the second migration was a little bit tricky. You have to run

```
./manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Comment: this was helpful