# Django model query isn't going through

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a very simple app that requests users to add the name of a city into a poll and then creates a frequency distribution of entered cities. My view for some reason is not retrieving City objects from the database by their name (primary key). Specifically, the first assignment after `try:` is not going through, according to my trace statements. Must be overlooking something really obvious as I'm a novice. Please advise.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='20', primary_key=True)
    count = 0
```

views.py:

```
def save(request):
name = request.POST['city_name']
try:
    city = City.objects.get(pk=name)
    print 'city does exist'
    city.count += 1
except City.DoesNotExist:
    print 'city does not exist'
    city = City()
    city.name = name
    city.count += 1
city.save()
return render_to_response('thanks.html', {'city_name':name})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `city.save()` after changing `city.count`

You will need to do this in the `try` block and `except` block.

Comment: No problem, we all do it from time-to-time :)  Sometimes it just needs a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: @entrepaul what should city.count be? The number of all cities so far? Then try City.objects.count()

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='20', primary_key=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

As a side note, (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) may help clean things up a bit.

Edit:

Comment: I think every time you get a City object the count will always be 0 and isn't actually saved to the database. I've not tested it out, so I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Ok I think you're right, so I've changed it to count = IntegerField(default=0), but now it does not recognize count as a database table even after I do syncdb... Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Running syncdb won't add to an existing schema. You can drop the City table or use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) to manage schema migrations. Another solution would be to manually add the count column as an integer field in the database.

Comment: How do I drop the City table into the db?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286276/how-do-i-drop-a-table-from-sqlite3-in-django) points out you can run: python manage.py reset app_name