# Django DB error with nonexistent table

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models

I try to reinitialize my DB and I have this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app_evaluation

I don't have any variable with this name, I try to dele db.sqlite3 and all files of migrations folder and run the migrate and makemigrations command but nothings works

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField
from site_.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
class Criterion(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def  __str__(self):
        return self.label
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default = '')
    github = models.URLField(default = '')
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100, default = '')
    cover_letter = models.TextField(default = '')
    higher_education = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    average = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    #############################################################score = models.ForeignKey()
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='/home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-second-blog/site_/media', null=True, blank=True)
    def  __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, unique=True)
    #s_candidate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    criterion = models.ForeignKey(Criterion, default='')
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
    appraiser = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.candidate)
class avarage(models.Model):
    eva = Evaluation.objects.get()
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Candidate, Criterion, Evaluation
from django import forms
from .forms import CandForm
from .forms import EvalForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def canditate_list(request):
    candidates = Candidate.objects.all()

    eva = Evaluation.objects.all()
    eval_cand_list = []                                     #aqui guarda uma lista com os FK candidates convertidos p/ str

    context = {
        'candidates': candidates,
        'eva': eva
    }
    return render(request, 'app/candidate_list.html',context)

def candidate_detail(request, pk):
    candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pk=pk)
    c_name = candidate.name                                 #pega o nome (string) do candidato
    c1 = Evaluation.objects.all()                           #guarda tds Evaluation na variavel  
    scores = []                                             #declara a array que vai receber as notas
    for c in c1:                                            
        cand = str(c.candidate)                             #guarda o nome do candidato do Evaluation atual
        if cand == c_name:                                  #confere se o Evaluation atual corresponde ao candidate atual(pk)
            scores += [c.score]

    _sum = 0                                                #variavel que guardara a soma declarada
    for s in scores:
        _sum += s                                           #faz a soma dos scores

    average = _sum/len(scores)                              #tira a média

    context = {
        'candidate': candidate,
        'average': average
    }



    return render(request, 'app/candidate_detail.html', context)

def evaluation(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)

        if form2.is_valid():    
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('canditate_list') 

    else:
        form2 = EvalForm()
        return render(request, 'app/evaluation.html', {'criterions': form2,})


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('candidate_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CandForm()
    return render(request, 'app/register.html', {'form': form})
```

[EDIT]:

I try to follow this: [How do I drop a table from SQLite3 in DJango?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286276/how-do-i-drop-a-table-from-sqlite3-in-django) tips but always the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django constructs db table names following convention `{app_label}_{model_name}` (lowercase). So it is referring to  `Evaluation` model. The problem is in `avarage` model, you are trying to use `Evaluation.objects.get()` in a model, but at that time the Evaluation model table is not yet created in the db. I believe you wanted to create a relationship but thats not how relationship works, what you need is the [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Comment: I get it! Thanks man but now I have another problem that don't happens before :(: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app_candidate

Comment: No problem, you can post a new question regarding your new problem :)

Comment: I was able to correct the error, there was no need to post the question, thank you, my friend!