# Django - 'sqlclear' equivalent in Django > 1.9

Tags: python, mysql, django

In Django 1.10.6, I made a model, and ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, it created a table in MySQL DB. Later I came to know that the table was not required. I searched and found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286276/how-do-i-drop-a-table-from-sqlite3-in-django). But that was for the versions before 1.9. In [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9) `sqlclear` has been removed. Now my doubt is,

> how can I drop a table from the DB using Django, for versions greater than 1.9?

Is there any `sqlclear` equivalent in versions greater than 1.9?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. Delete your Model for the Table or comment it out totally
2. python manage.py makemigrations 
3. python manage.migrate
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is getting affected by the previous migration files. For e.g., I had a function for image upload, and its is throwing an `AttributeError` because of that from the previous migration files.

Comment: so you need to delete the migrations files except the init.py file in the migrations folder

Comment: Did you got what you wanted bro

Comment: I had to comment out all those lines causing `AttributeError` in the `migrations file`. Now its working. Thanks.